# Javascript timesheet inconsistent functionality

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an html/javascript timesheet for my organization, and though I've gotten it to do the calculations correctly, it doesn't seem to be doing them consistently. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Each of the inputs does this:

```
<input type="text" name="date-1-out" id="date-1-out" size="5" placeholder="" maxlength="5" onchange="date1calc()" />
```

So for date-1-out, date-1-lunch, date-1-sick, etc, each is set to run the date1calc() function when the input is changed. When I select date-1-out, it gives me an accurate subtotal (time out minus time in), but when I select a value for date-1-lunch, bonus, sick, vacation or holiday, it will not update the total. But if I select date-1-out and choose a different out time, it will update the total and subtotal with the correct numbers.

This is the javascript:

```
// Convert hh:mm[am/pm] to minutes
function timeStringToMins(s) {
  s = s.split(':');
  return s[0]*60 + parseInt(s[1]) + (/pm$/i.test(s[1])? 720 : 0);
}

// Return difference between two times in hh:mm[am/pm] format as hh:mm
function getTimeDifferenceSubtotal(timein, timeout, lunch) {
// Small helper function to pad single digits
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
// Get difference in minutes
  var subtotal = timeStringToMins(timeout) - timeStringToMins(timein) - timeStringToMins(lunch);
// Format difference as hh:mm and return
  return   z(subtotal/60 | 0) + ':' + z(subtotal % 60); 
}

// Return difference between two times in hh:mm[am/pm] format as hh:mm
function getTimeDifference(timein, timeout, lunch, bonus, sick, vacation, holiday) {
// Small helper function to pad single digits
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
// Get difference in minutes
  var total = timeStringToMins(timeout) - timeStringToMins(timein) - timeStringToMins(lunch) - timeStringToMins(bonus) - timeStringToMins(sick) - timeStringToMins(vacation) - timeStringToMins(holiday);
// Format difference as hh:mm and return
  return   z(total/60 | 0) + ':' + z(total % 60); 
}

// Run this function every time a date-1 cell is changed
function date1calc() {
if (document.getElementById("date-1-in").value == '') {var timein = '00:00';} else {var timein = document.getElementById("date-1-in").value;}
if (document.getElementById("date-1-out").value == '') {var timeout = '00:00';} else {var timeout = document.getElementById("date-1-out").value;}
if (document.getElementById("date-1-lunch").value == '') {var lunch = '00:00';} else {var lunch = document.getElementById("date-1-lunch").value;}
if (document.getElementById("date-1-bonus").value == '') {var bonus = '00:00';} else {var bonus = document.getElementById("date-1-bonus").value;}
if (document.getElementById("date-1-sick").value == '') {var sick = '00:00';} else {var sick = document.getElementById("date-1-sick").value;}
if (document.getElementById("date-1-vacation").value == '') {var vacation = '00:00';} else {var vacation = document.getElementById("date-1-vacation").value;}
if (document.getElementById("date-1-holiday").value == '') {var holiday = '00:00';} else {var holiday = document.getElementById("date-1-holiday").value;}
document.getElementById("date-1-subtotal").value = getTimeDifferenceSubtotal(timein, timeout, lunch);
document.getElementById("date-1-total").value = getTimeDifference(timein, timeout, lunch, bonus, sick, vacation, holiday);
}
```

Is it bad to run the same function each time? Or am I missing something somewhere else? Or is it failing because I'm running the same date1calc() script each time?

EDIT: It works if I change the HTML in the input from "onchange='date1calc()'" to "onblur='date1calc()'" for the lunch, bonus, sick, vacation & holiday fields. Is there a functionality to "onchange" that I don't get?

EDIT 2: Maybe this is an HTML issue with using onchange with the jquery autocomplete to give an automatic dropdown menu

Comment: Why aren't you calculating all this on the server?

Comment: It seemed like it would be better to calculate it on the client side since I don't have a database to save it to yet - right now when it submits I'll be using PHP to send it to our operations manager

Comment: Seems like you'd be opening yourself up to vulnerabilities, a tech-savvy user may be able to manipulate their hours.

Comment: Right now it's just emailing the op manager who processes the timesheets, this is just to replace doing them in excel as everyone hates excel. But I plan on writing a rails app for the backend so i can add in verification then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your fields that are blank do not experience the change event until they are populated and THEN change. If you put default value of 0:00 when the page initializes then your user changes the values, this will trigger the update.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the Firefox's Web Console.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML so I can test the javascript?

Comment: I put the whole thing up at http://jasonboyce.com/timesheet/ts_test.html since there's a ton of HTML. I only have functionality for the first date

Comment: My mistake, I didn't mean tto say that date-1-in calls the date1calc function - I changed date-1-in to enableOut() so that the date-1-out input is disabled until the user selects a time in so that they don't pick a time out before they pick a time in.

Comment: It looks like the onchange event is not triggered when you update bonus, sick, vacation, holiday. You can verify if this is the case by adding an additional javascript method to the onchange event such as an alert("change event"); or console.log("change event"); See if this is triggered when you change a value.

Comment: Since you are using jquery, how about setting up an on change listener on all these input elements when they change? http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I'm trying the jquery change listener but doesn't seem to be working. Right now my code is: $(function() { $( "#date-1-lunch" ).change(date1calc() {});})

Comment: Try putting your listener inside a ready function so the listener is created once the DOM is ready. $(document).ready(function(){$( "#date-1-lunch" ).change(date1calc() {});}); Also you might try different selector for your listener eg $("input").change() or $(".ui-autocomplete-input").change();